# Modern UI (Metro) style tile in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, modern-ui

I would like to know if it's possible to recreate the tile system of modern UI from Windows 8 on a HTML page.

I already created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B4st13n/P45bE/) from [this website](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/techdays/2013/Home.aspx#p=sessions). Here is the code

```
<div class="tile pos1-1 w1h1 techolive"></div>
<div class="tile pos1-2 w1h1 techblue"></div>
<div class="tile pos2-2 w1h1 techred"></div>
<div class="tilebanner" style="font-size: 20px !important;">
    <a class="tile pos2-3 w2h1 techdarkblue" href="...">
                    List of<br/>
                    Sessions
    </a>
</div>
```

Now i would like to add the same [slide movement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YkNJN_g-sw) effect of modern UI. I guest I need javaScript to create that. Perhaps this feature or a similar feature is included in HTML 5 or CSS. Do you know where I can find a sample?

Comment: I just found this but it's a tool, no real code. I would like to code this to create website : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MB4PqHhEbU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin for jQuery called [Metro JS](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs). Maybe you can use this to create the tiles with jquery and javascript.

Comment: @David Chase: You're right. I used German grammar. Corrected my answer.

Comment: lol i mean like the Apple saying ["There's app for the that"](http://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/mobile/10/12/app.for.that/index.html), i am saying "there's a plugin for that" nothing to do with your grammer :)

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking at this now should check out [MetroUI](http://metroui.org.ua/) - it follows a very similar methodology to Twitter Bootstrap and is very easy to use and produces really nice results.

It's also:

> Developed with the advice of Microsoft to build the user interface

So you get something really true to Windows 8